# List all global variables in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to list all of the global variables, including those refering to [built-in objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects).

In Chrome's console I can simply type `this` and get back all the keys, including things like `String`, `Number`, etc.

However when I do this in Node.js I get much less:

```
> Object.keys(this)
[ 'global',
  'process',
  'GLOBAL',
  'root',
  'Buffer',
  'setTimeout',
  'setInterval',
  'clearTimeout',
  'clearInterval',
  'setImmediate',
  'clearImmediate',
  'console',
  'module',
  'require',
  '_' ]
> this.eval
[Function: eval]
```

Where is `this.eval` coming from?

Comment: Try `Object.keys(Object.getPrototypeOf(this))` and `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)` (for inherited and non-enumerable properties respectively)

Comment: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)` did the trick, thanks @Bergi!

Comment: In a file, it's loaded as a module, where `this` is not the global object.

Comment: console.log(global); ?

Comment: node -p "Object.getOwnPropertyNames(global)"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The built-in properties of the global object are non-enumerable, so [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) doesn't return them. You can use [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) instead.

Comment: For anyone working with some in-browser coding tools, like codepen, [tslang](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play), etc, be aware this answer will not work, and you need to test with a local tool like `ts-node`, or in the browser console directly

Comment: @NewAlexandria [Works fine for me](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/MYewdgziA2CmB00QHMAUB5ARgK1sALvMrPugO5gAKATiAA6zX4CeAcgIYC2sEqEs0AGYBKYQG4gA)

Comment: It does not work, I get `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Comment: @user5359531 What code did you run and where? Apparently you did not pass the global object.

Comment: I ran `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)`

Comment: @user5359531 And *where*? The value of `this` depends on a lot of things, and apparently your `this` is not the global object. Use something else.

Comment: looks like its running [here](https://github.com/common-workflow-language/cwltool/blob/main/cwltool/sandboxjs.py#L146);  `node --eval ...`

Comment: @user5359531 `node --eval 'console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this))'` works just fine for me

Answer (score 11):

The following `globals()` function will get you global namespace object:

```
function globals() { return this; }
```

With it you can list all variables of global namespace anytime you want:

```
function varsList() {
  return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(globals());
}
```

UPDATE:

In modern browsers you can use *globalThis* namespace object that holds variables of global namespace:

```
function globalVarsList() {
  return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(globalThis);
}

for(const name of globalVarsList()) {
   console.log(name); 
}
```

This will work in strict mode too.

Comment: And in strict mode? ;-)

Comment: it does not work, I get `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)`
.As without passing the "this" as argument or parameter referring to Object owner's properties, the getOwnPropertyNames() function won't return anything.

Answering your question as to where the eval comes from check this link out.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval