# display ALL variables in a node js script

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to get a list of ALL variables (and their values) at that place in a node js script?

Not only like displaying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31173579/3883682).

Also globals like this:

```
var http = require('http'),
util = require('util'),
fs   = require('fs');
```

And also the super-globals ones like the node js: [process](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html) or [console](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html). Really ALL possible variables at that moment ?

Comment: not programmically afaik but a good ide will probably have a debug tool to do something close to what you're asking. Eclipse debugger can do this for java but I've never tried for javascript.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051678/getting-all-variables-in-scope

Comment: I'd REALLY like to know the answer to this.  Starting to get pretty good at Node, but I'm coming from the PHP world and some things are just kind of dumb in Node.

Comment: In PHP you could just do "print_r($GLOBALS);" or even "print_r($POST);" and it'll print everything in the whole script, or in all the POST requests.  Node just seems to make this stuff unnecessarily hard.