# How to list all declared variables in running nodejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know this sound likes an already answered question but I looked at [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173473/list-all-global-variables-in-node-js) and tried the solution to no avail. `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)` returns `[]` and `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(global)` does show a lot of variables but any variables I declared **in the program that is running the console interface** isn't a part of this `global` variable. I made a [repl](https://replit.com/@PaulTaylor2/ReadLine-Console) to my console interface and to explain what I mean, running it then entering `values` will return an array, but I would like some list **THAT HAS THESE VARIABLES**

If you don't want to/can't run the [repl](https://replit.com/@PaulTaylor2/ReadLine-Console), the code is below, save it as something and `node filename` to see what I mean.

The problem, again, is that I want some list that includes all the variables declared in the program(`global` doesn't have what I want and the variables are very accessible because when you run the program and enter `values` it appears but if you can find some list that has `values` I would be grateful)

```
var readline=require('readline');
const values = ['lorem ipsum', 'dolor sit amet']; //I want some list that has these variables
String.prototype.l=String.prototype.toLowerCase //shorter version of toLowerCase is now l
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: true,
  historySize: 50,
  tabSize: 2,
  completer: function(line) {var hits=[]; var hitlist=[]
    const completions = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(global)
    function search1(c,l){return c.startsWith(l)}
    function search2(c,l){return c.includes(l)&&c.startsWith(l)}
    //ordering suggestions
    hitlist.push( completions.filter(c=>search1(c,line)).sort() )
    hitlist.push( completions.filter(c=>search1(c.l(),line.l())).sort() )
    hitlist.push( completions.filter(c=>search2(c,line)).sort() )
    hitlist.push( completions.filter(c=>search2(c.l(),line.l())).sort() )
    hitlist.push( rl.history.filter(c=>search1(c,line)).sort() )
    hitlist.push( rl.history.filter(c=>search1(c.l(),line.l())).sort() )
    hitlist.push( rl.history.filter(c=>search2(c,line)).sort() )
    hitlist.push( rl.history.filter(c=>search2(c.l(),line.l())).sort() )
    //placing suggestions in one list
    hitlist.forEach(a=>a.forEach(b=>{ if(hits.indexOf(b)==-1){hits.push(b)} }))
    return [hits.length?hits:[],line]
  }
});
rl.on('line',(line)=>{try{console.log(eval(line))} catch(e){console.error(e)}})
```

I'm not depending on the answer being from `readline` im just showing WHY I want to get the in-file declared variables(for tab suggestions)

Comment: a lot of people say this is impossible but why is it? when the console runs it proves that the variables are accessible, so where are they? where are they stored?

Comment: You cannot access them from the JS code - also why would you want to do that? But you can easily inspect the module scope with a debugger by placing a breakpoint in the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Babel plugin.

This is a Babel plugin that logs information about the variables and identifiers in the scope of a program.

```js
const { template } = require("@babel/core");
const generator = require("@babel/generator").default;

module.exports = function({ types: t }) {
  return {
     visitor: {
      Program(path) {
        t.addComment(path.container,"leading", `This is what I found:
Identifiers defined in this scope: ${JSON.stringify(Object.keys(path.scope.bindings))};
Identifiers used that are global or in prelude scope: ${JSON.stringify(Object.keys(path.scope.globals))}
All variables used at all: ${JSON.stringify(Object.keys(path.scope.references))}
`)
      }
    }
  };
};
```

So, Babel simply parses the file and transforms the code, and creates a comment that explains whatever it has found.

[Here](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/cc536e5919815cdb7220a33eee0fda28/8c6c5293d7cf76030ebd69f0f9cc8e5c5fe5c522) is an online demo. Hope, it helps.

Comment: I'm not ignoring u btw, I have school and haven't took the time yet to test out your answer ;-; tnx for it tho

Comment: Hopefully this helps you, this is how I understood the question.